# iOS how to extract command line arguments from string into NSDictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to parse a string, extract command line arguments and store them in an NSDictionary. I see that [something similar is already possible using NSUserdefaults](http://perspx.com/archives/parsing-command-line-arguments-nsuserdefaults/), as described below:

```
MyApplication -aString "Hello, World" -anInteger 10

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *aString = [standardDefaults stringForKey:@"aString"];
NSInteger anInteger = [standardDefaults integerForKey:@"anInteger"];
```

Is there a way to do generic argument extraction from any string into any NSDictionary using the format `-key value` ?

Comment: 1) This is tagged iOS. Why? You are not going to deal with command line args in an iOS app. 2) `NSUserDefaults` is not in any way related to command line arguments.

Comment: I have a console in an iOS app and I'm dealing with command line arguments typed in that console. The user defaults is just an example of what arguments look like

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I would say no - for this reason: NSDictionaries are not necessarily simple structures. For example, the "value" could be a primitive object, but it might be yet another NSDictionary or NSArray.  That being, said, if your string is in JSON format, that will map using any of the JSON libraries, including the one in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way, and in fact NSUserDefaults doesn't do this either — it just accesses the arguments that are passed to the program, not an arbitrary shell command. You'll have to parse it yourself. How complicated that would be depends on how much sophistication you need. For what you've shown here, an NSScanner that looks for spaces and matches quotes when found would be sufficient.